# Find Loop with Inner SumIFS

Tags: vba, excel, find, sumifs

this is my first time posting to the forum. i have been a novice programmer mainly for Excel VBA. usually simple codes to improve efficiency or accuracy of the information translated.

Currently i am faced with a project where there has been an error with my SumIFS formula.

The Database sheet is a sheet with the bulk load of information.the objective of the sumifs is to sum each week to the corresponding name and id.

the Database is linked with MS Access as well so that it remains dynamic with every update.

here are some fields in the Database which is crucial to the SUMIFS

ID - Column B
Name - Column C
Work - Column D
Period - Column F

xx is the cell row where the formula is to be input. 
LR is the last row (this is where the period is placed as well on the main sheet)

i would need to drag this formula across the sheet to the current week. therefore im looking at autofill properties as well. which explains my attempt to lock them by the rows

Below is the code in concern.

```
With Sheets(CurrSheet).Range(UppLimit, BtmLimit) _
    Set C = .Find("Actual", LookIn:=xlValues)
    If Not C Is Nothing Then
        firstAddress = C.Address
        Do

           xx = C.Offset(0, 2).Row
            MsgBox xx

            C.Offset(0, 2).Activate 
             activecell.formula= "SUMIFS(Database!$C:$C,Database!$F:$F,'2'!Range(LR,i),Database!$B:$B,'2'!Range(xx,1),Database!$C:$C,'2'!Range(xx,3),Database!$D:$D,'2'!Range($C$1)""

            i = i + 1



            Set C = .FindNext(C)
            If C Is Nothing Then
                GoTo DoneFinding
            End If
            Loop While Not C Is Nothing And C.Address <> firstAddress
    End If
DoneFinding:
End With
```

Comment: screen shot might help

Comment: you need to define like this `Database!$F:$F," & worksheets("2").cells(lr,1).address & ",Database..."` the formula should look as it does when you enter it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your actual formula works correctly, this should work:

```
activecell.formula = "=SUMIFS(Database!$C:$C,Database!$F:$F,2!" & Cells(LR, i).Address & ",Database!$B:$B,2!" & Cells(xx, 1).Address & ",Database!$C:$C,2!" & Cells(xx, 3).Address & ",Database!$D:$D,2!" & Cells(1, 3).Address & ")"
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me with this. the formula works great now. Thank you so much